# How can I take only integer input from keyboard and if input is invalid how do I ask user again?

Tags: java, validation

This is what I have written so far but when exception is raised it does not again ask the user for input.

```
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of stones to play with: ");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  
        String temp = br.readLine();
        key = Integer.parseInt(temp);
    } while (key < 0 && key > 9);

    if (key < 0 || key > 10)
        throw new InvalidStartingStonesException(key);

    player1 = new KeyBoardPlayer();
    player2 = new KeyBoardPlayer(); 
    this.player1 = player1;
    this.player2 = player2;
    state = new KalaGameState(key);
} catch (NumberFormatException nFE) {
    System.out.println("Not an Integer");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: The code indeed doesn't do that. You've asked similar question with another account before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614930/i-am-getting-exception-in-main-thread-even-when-i-am-handling-the-exception Please register your account and stick to one and same account: http://www.google.com/search?q=InvalidStartingStonesException+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3):

As soon as that `NumberFormatException` is thrown, you jump out of the loop and down to the `catch`.  If your `try`-`catch` block is *inside* your `while` loop, it'll have the effect you're looking for.  You may need to adjust the condition on the loop.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to check if the string input matches a regular expression for an integer. If it doesn't match, you ask for the input again.

Answer (score 0):

See [Teleteype.readInt()](http://code.google.com/p/java-project-template/source/browse/trunk/src/com/yourcompanyname/projectname/Teletype.java) from the [Java Project Template](http://code.google.com/p/java-project-template/). The basics of it is that you read input as a String, and then you convert it to an integer using [Integer.parseInt()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29), which will throw [NumberFormatException](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) if the contents of the String is not an integer, which you can handle by catching the NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is instead of using all these exceptions is to make separate methods that read specific data types. (Ex.)

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int n = getInteger("Enter integer: ");

    System.out.println(n);

}

public static boolean isInteger(String s){

    if(s.isEmpty())return false;
    for (int i = 0; i <s.length();++i){
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(!Character.isDigit(c) && c !='-')
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static int getInteger(String prompt){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String in = "";
    System.out.println(prompt);
    in = input.nextLine();
    while(!isInteger(in)){
        System.out.println(prompt);
        in = input.nextLine();
    }

    return Integer.parseInt(in);

}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
while (true) {
   System.out.println("Enter the number of stones to play with: ");
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  
   key = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
   if (key > -1 && key < 10)
      break;
   else
      System.out.println("Invalid number of stones. Choose from 0 - 9");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't handle the `NumberFormatException` -- and also, this being (I suspect) a homework problem, let's maybe prefer good hints over explicitly writing out the solution.